# kotlin firebase multiple loop

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

when I add multiple loop to retrieve data from firebase only the first loop works, why is that happening and how can I make all the loops work

```
 val children = dataSnapshot!!.children
    children.forEach {
        if( it.child("Date").getValue().toString().equals(Data.date) && it.child("Time").getValue().toString().equals(Data.time) && it.child("location").getValue().toString().equals(items.get(0).toString())){
            //
        }

    }

children.forEach {
        if( it.child("Date").getValue().toString().equals(Data.date) && it.child("Time").getValue().toString().equals(Data.time) && it.child("location").getValue().toString().equals(items.get(1).toString())){
            //
        }

    }

children.forEach {
        if( it.child("Date").getValue().toString().equals(Data.date) && it.child("Time").getValue().toString().equals(Data.time) && it.child("location").getValue().toString().equals(items.get(2).toString())){
            //
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Why don't you use a single forEach loop and put all the if statements in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance the 3 loops look identical, but they differ at the last 3d of the condition. 
 Each one checks this:

```
it.child("location").getValue().toString().equals(items.get(x).toString())
```

where x is 0, 1 or 2. 
So they are not the same as to be surprised why the last 2 don't work as you say. 
Maybe the condition works only for:

```
items.get(0).toString()
```

Anyway you can simplify your code and add some debugging code so to be sure what's happening:

```
(0..2).forEach { i ->
    children.forEach {
        val dateOk = it.child("Date").getValue().toString().equals(Data.date)
        val timeOk = it.child("Time").getValue().toString().equals(Data.time)
        val itemOk = it.child("location").getValue().toString().equals(items.get(i).toString())

        Log.d("Loop", "at $i: dateOk = $dateOk, timeOk = $timeOk, itemOk = $itemOk")
        if( dateOk && timeOk && itemOk){
            when (i) {
                0 -> //
                1 -> //
                2 -> //
            }
        }
    }
}
```